# to replace or not replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, str-replace

I am trying to swap out given strings within a message however I found that there are signifgant performance costs with my approach (see below).

```
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.MessageDescription, '{{DeploymentDate}}', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), d.ExpiryDate, 106), '')),
                                '{{EndOfMonthExpiryDate}}', CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)), 120) + '.00'),
                        '{{ExpiryDays}}', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), d.ApprovalExpiryDate)), '')), '{{TermEndDate}}',
                ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), d.term_end_date, 106), '')) ,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.MessageExpiryText, '{{DeploymentDate}}', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), d.ApprovalExpiryDate, 106), '')),
                                '{{EndOfMonthExpiryDate}}', CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)), 120) + '.00'),
                        '{{ExpiryDays}}', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), d.ApprovalExpiryDate)), '')), '{{TermEndDate}}',
                ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), d.term_end_date, 106), ''))
FROM    AudienceMessages m
        INNER JOIN AudienceCommunication d ON d.mID = d.dID
```

I was hoping someone out there had come across this issue and have found a better performing approach to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I've heard somewhere that is the resulting string of the replace operation is not the same length then Replace operation will perform badly. Try to make your tags the same size as the expected values they represent

Comment: It will be better if you show some sample data and expected output. The query is not readable.

Comment: It seems you are trying to do something that a backend coding langauge could do much better and effeciently. Is returning all the rows and parsing through them in code an option?

Comment: You really need to use something like SQL Pretty Printer - http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm ..  Also, you really need to get rid of the "NESTED" REPLACEs `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE`..  You should only need one Replace per element - IMHO.